# Passing in an SDL_Event* into a method

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing, sdl-2

I want to time text input in SDL2 to not spam it at 1000 key presses per second, rather the standard which is like ~33kps.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


#include "main.h"

void Main::Init()
{
    std::cout << "Main Init called\n";

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    Get_Instance().window = SDL_CreateWindow("Program", 0, 30, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
    Get_Instance().renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Get_Instance().window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED  );

    Get_Instance().running = true;

}



void Main::Free()
{

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(Get_Instance().renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(Get_Instance().window);


    SDL_Quit();

    std::cout << "Main Free called\n";

}



void Main::Mainloop()
{

    Get_Instance(); ///To initialize constructor

    if (Get_Instance().mainloopInstanceBlocker == 'C')
    {
        Get_Instance().mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'B';   ///Begins at I (initialized), then C (constructed) then B (began)
                                        ///It works as it begins as constructed, then does the main loop, after set to B, won't enter again.


        Get_Instance().Init();

        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_StartTextInput();



        while (Get_Instance().running)
        {

            ///Poll events
            SDL_PollEvent(&event);


            ///To quit program
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT ){
                Get_Instance().running = false;
                break;
            }



            ///Clear display to color
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Get_Instance().renderer, 0,255,0,255);
            SDL_RenderClear(Get_Instance().renderer);



            Get_Instance().m_Main_Loop.Mainloop( Get_Instance().window, Get_Instance().renderer, &event );


            SDL_RenderPresent(Get_Instance().renderer);
        }



        SDL_StopTextInput();


        Get_Instance().Free();


    }
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Main::Mainloop();

    return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include "main_loop.h"



class Main
{
public:
    Main(const Main&) = delete;
    Main(Main&&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(const Main&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(Main&&) = delete;


    static void Mainloop();




private:
    Main()
    {
        std::cout << "Main constructor called\n";
        mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'C';
    }

    static Main& Get_Instance()
    {
        static Main instance;
        return instance;
    }


    static void Init();
    static void Free();



    Main_Loop m_Main_Loop;

    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    bool running = false;
    char mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'I';



};








#endif // MAIN_H
```

**main_loop.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_LOOP_H
#define MAIN_LOOP_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>


class Main_Loop
{
public:
    Main_Loop();
    ~Main_Loop();


    void Mainloop(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Event* event);




};




#endif // MAIN_LOOP_H
```

**main_loop.cpp**

```
#include "main_loop.h"




Main_Loop::Main_Loop()
{

}


void Main_Loop::Mainloop(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Event* event)
{
    if (event->type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
    {
        std::cout << event->text.text << std::endl;
    }


}





Main_Loop::~Main_Loop()
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry not clear what you intend to do and what your problem seems to be. You just did take a pointer of your event structure - with `&event`. `SDL_PollEvent` writes event data into specified structure, so with each call it could overwrite previous contents.

Comment: I managed to fix it, Just not to call it in the while loop, rather just the actual function ```SDL_PollEvent()``` itself. I have another problem, however, with ```if (event->type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)``` where if you hold down a key to input text, it inputs the text at like 1000 characters a second. How can I make it such that it times it like any other text application, ie, you hold down a key and it spams it after a small snippet of time about ~33 keys per second (same with backspace, delete) @keltar

Comment: I need to see your code to answer that. SDL uses system's key repeat, so it should behave the same way as in other programs.

Comment: Ok since the original q got fixed ill post my code/reedit the question @keltar

Comment: if you run that code, the second you type a letter it will spam it about 1000 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

```
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
```

`SDL_PollEvent` returns 0 if there are no more events in the queue, but in that case it doesn't write anything into passed event structure. Since you no longer check return value of `PollEvent`, you operate on stale data left by last event you've had. At the very least do something like

```
if(!SDL_PollEvent(&event)) event.type = 0;
```

Your `Mainloop` function is questionable - does it imply there could be only one event per frame? What'd you do if there are multiple events happened in single frame? I'd suggest separating event processing and rendering - i.e. make event processing function that handles entire event queue and reacts to events by modifying your data, and separate rendering function that only does rendering.

Comment: Can it only handle one event though? I'm passing a pointer to the entire ```SDL_Event``` struct so it would have access to all its members?

Comment: No, `SDL_Event` only contains single event. That's why you use `while(SDL_PollEvent())` loop to fetch event, process its contents, fetch next event, ...

Comment: Oh wow okay, thats definitely gonna make things much more difficult, okay

Comment: This might be too broad a question, but if I want rendering and event processing separate to allow multiple events in a loop, how would I structure my ```Mainloop``` or such to make that work? Because If objects move based on events and then I have to render them in a separate part how would you structure that?

Comment: There is more than one way to do it, but generally - in event handling function you react to events and update states (e.g. raising "move forward is pressed" flag), in update function you iterate over all objects that needs updating and set new position etc. (this part needs to be ran un locked interval or be aware of how much time passed after last update), and in render function you iterate over all objects that needs to be drawn and draw them. Of course there could be a lot of specifics on how things are updated or drawn, but basic idea is still the same.